# What is an antonym of -wards?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

In words as *eastwards* and *leftwards*, *-ward* or *-wards* indicates the direction the object moves to. What is an adjective suffix for movement in the direction from? Needless to say, but metaphorical and analogical meanings are of interest here.

Comment: Strangely an *easterly* wind comes from the east, but if I walk in an easterly direction it's towards the east.

Comment: I don't think there is a suffix which means the opposite of '-ward'.

Comment: That seems to be exclusively about wind. It is still interpreted this way without any suffix e.g. *a north wind* is blowing from the north. I am not aware of any definite reason why this is the case. One reason I've seen is that it is the direction that weather vanes (ha!, that's your username) face.

Comment: @WeatherVane - You may want to lookup the definition of *easterly*.  An *easterly* wind [adjective] blows toward the east from the west.  An *easterly* [noun] blows toward the west from the east.  Nonplussed, anyone?

Comment: @EllieK I think you may have misread it. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/easterly) gives: in or towards the east, or blowing from the east... easterly wind: a wind that blows from the east.

Comment: @EllieK - '_An easterly wind [adjective] blows toward the east from the west._' I'm nonplussed. Can you provide a source for that?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Oxford Dictionary?  https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=easterly

Comment: @EllieK your link does not mention the wind, only supporting my [first comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/349277/what-is-the-antonym-of-wards#comment679537_349277). An easterly, or an easterly wind, blows from the east.

Comment: Sorry, I've been away for awhile.  Easterly winds blow from the east.  Webster's gives both definitions, which prompted the nonplussed comment.

Comment: @Weather Vane The more comprehensive Oxford English Dictionary gives more support for your understanding, I think.

Comment: So I will in the mathematical text, where this is of interest, take the arrow in A => True "A" to be truthwards, and the one in  A <= True "A" to be truthly. Arrows are much like vanes, so the usage seems justified.

Comment: "Blow the Wind Southerly" is a traditional English folk song from Northumbria (in the northernmost part of England). It tells of a woman desperately hoping for a southerly wind to blow her lover back home over the sea to her.

Comment: Note, comments are not part of the official question, or for ongoing discussion. Most of the comments are about wind. If the question wants to focus on wind, please edit to make that clear. If it's about mathematical vectors, please edit to make *that* clear.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a similar suffix that works in all situations. Most often, you can simply express the idea either by using multiple words, e.g. the opposite of "The ship sailed southwards" could be "the ship sailed out of the north." Often, for most clarity, both the "from" and "towards" are specified, even if they are opposites: "He paced across the room from right to left, and then from left to right again."

A few special circumstances have specialized words for certain directions; for instance, in nautical terminology, "windward" is the direction *from* which the wind is blowing, and "leeward" is the direction *toward* which it's blowing. In other cases, the origin of a thing is an aspect of its description, so a suffix of *-ern* or similar might be appropriate ("The kingdom was invaded by tribes from the east" -> "eastern tribes.") But these suffixes vary ("pol*ar*," "tropic*al*"), and of course a direction *isn't* always a part of something's identity.

Comment: Windward still means "towards the wind".

Comment: @Andy Bonner Look up -ly in Oxford English Dictionary to see that the comments by Weather Wane above are quite to the point, and to see that -ly occurs in many other constructions indicating origin. Compare also my second comment above.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I'm not sure adding "-ly" works with much besides compass-point directions. I don't know that one can say "leftly" or "truthly," without first explaining your specialized usage. I strongly encourage you to edit your question if your interest is more specific than *the body of the question itself* (not comments) currently indicates.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think we're disagreeing. "Windward" and "leeward" were developed to talk not about the wind (of course it blows from windward toward leeward!) but to talk about us and other objects in relation to it. But it does somewhat fit the OP's desire for a word expressing something's direction in a way that speaks about origin. (If only in a very niche application.)

Comment: Those two terms are very much about the wind, but not my DV.

Comment: @AndyBonner Certainly, there are many things earthly creatures are not so sure about. OED, which I mentioned, is a source for many examples on the use of -ly.